# Lighthouse (v10) performance scores changed to lower values

Tags: performance-testing, lighthouse, web-testing

I'm optimizing my site (see: https://jekyll-one-org.github.io/) for better (Google) Lighthouse scores and found the performance scoring changed to lower values. For example:

LCP, should lower/equal 2.5 for the green level, but the current measureseems to be at **1.9**

For modern websites, loading parts of content dynamically is important for a good user experience. I think a measure of LCP at 1.9 is unrealistic for most web servers. I have tested several web servers (EngineX, Puma, Github Pages, Netlify) online  for my site, and in most cases I couldn't reach a green level for FCP or LCP.

All the web servers provide excellent performance, and providers like Github and Netlify support CDNs for the best download speeds out of all worldwide regions.

Do I'm wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat confusingly Lighthouse does not use the traditional Core Web Vitals thresholds (e.g. 2.5 seconds for LCP), but instead are based on the as [noted in the linked documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/performance-scoring/) and can be seen in their [calculator](https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse/scorecalc/#FCP=3000&SI=5800&FMP=4000&TTI=7300&FCI=6500&LCP=1220&TBT=600&CLS=0.25&device=desktop&version=10). This has not new in Version 10 as can be seen by trying out previous versions in that calculator - previous versions also had their own limits.

The mobile thresholds are pretty similar to the official Core Web Vitals metrics (e.g. 2.5 seconds for LCP), but the desktop ones (which run at a faster rate than their mobile tests) are set at a more difficult threshold (I get 1.2 seconds not 1.9 seconds).

This is in part because the thresholds for Core Web Vitals are set the same for mobile and desktop, in part for simplicity reasons, and in part because in the real world there is not a always a clear distinction (the latest high-spec Android phone running on 5G or even WiFi can out perform a desktop computer).

For Lighthouse however, it runs the tests under two very specific conditions, and the mobile test is throttled more on both CPU and Network. Therefore it makes little sense to keep the thresholds the same for the test which is supposed to highlight performance opportunities for both desktop and mobile runs.

Additionally Lighthouse is often run from the actual URL, on a ready server with potentially cached content on the server(s), often close to the end server. Whereas in real life users are often coming via redirects, or for a server that needs to wake up or perform queries to render a page, and can often be coming from the other side of the world. So it is in fact good that there is a more strict threshold in the Desktop scores compared to what you really need, to allow for those extra latencies in the real world.

It is very possible for sites to get passing green scores on Lighthouse even with these stricter limits. Getting a 100 score is a tougher challenger as that is a deliberately high bar. And [the documentation warns not to get too obsessive about this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/performance-scoring/):

> Going a bit deeper, the Lighthouse scoring curve model uses HTTPArchive data to determine two control points that then set the shape of a log-normal curve. The 25th percentile of HTTPArchive data becomes a score of 50 (the median control point), and the 8th percentile becomes a score of 90 (the good/green control point). While exploring the scoring curve plot below, note that between 0.50 and 0.92, there's a near-linear relationship between metric value and score. Around a score of 0.96 is the "point of diminishing returns" as above it, the curve pulls away, requiring increasingly more metric improvement to improve an already high score.

and further down:

> To provide a good user experience, sites should strive to have a good score (90-100). A "perfect" score of 100 is extremely challenging to achieve and not expected. For example, taking a score from 99 to 100 needs about the same amount of metric improvement that would take a 90 to 94.

At the end of the day, Lighthouse is a diagnostic tool intended to highlight potential performance improvements. I would worry less about achieving the best possible score on this, and instead produce a fast site that scores highly on this, and then measure your real users ([PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) gives this along with Lighthouse data) to see how reflective Lighthouse is of your end users. You may find it's overly pessimistic or overly optimistic. And either is fine as long as you understand that.